# React native bottom navigation in main screen

Tags: javascript, android, react-native

I have 2 screens. 
First one is **Login screen**(without header) where I have "createStackNavigation" 
and second one is Main screen where I would like to have bottom navigation(2 tabs) with Header in each of these two tabs.

I did bottom navigation but custom header does not work at all...It's only basic header. Can anyone have some basic example of this? Or can help me with tutorial?

My code in app.js:

```
const RootStack = createStackNavigator(
{
 Home: {
  screen: Login,

 navigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => ({
    header: null,
 }),

},
 Main: MainScreen,

},
{
 initialRouteName: 'Home',
 headerMode: 'screen',

}
);
```

My code in "Main" screen:

```
export default createBottomTabNavigator(
{
  Domov: {
    screen: HomeScreen,

  },
  Dnevnik: Diary,
},
{
  navigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => ({
     tabBarIcon: ({ focused, tintColor }) => {
       const { routeName } = navigation.state;
       let iconName;
       if (routeName === 'Domov') {

       iconName='home';
       } else if (routeName === 'Dnevnik') {

         iconName='ios-calendar';
       } 


   return (
       <Icon name={iconName} style={{fontSize: 20, color: '#FFF'}} />
   );
 },

 }),
   tabBarPosition: 'bottom',
   tabBarOptions: {
   activeTintColor: 'white',
   showLabel: false,
   inactiveTintColor: '#4C2601',
   style: {
     backgroundColor: '#033D51',
   },
 },

});
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Add `header: null` in your `navigationOptions` in Main screen. You'll be able to add your custom header.

Comment: This one does not work...
I've added this header to my HomeScreen:
static navigationOptions = ({navigation}) => {
     return {
       headerTitle: "Dodaj"
     };
  };